# How to test a tree-shaking component library (ESM format) using jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest, rollup, tree-shaking

I've created a component library with storybook6 (React - Typescript) and I'm using Rollup for build.
The project that imports all these components from the library all works and also the bundle size si small as expected. And here is the problem, I have to write unit tests using jest and it fails:

```
// app.test.tsx

Cannot find module 'my-library' from 'src/app.tsx'

    Require stack:
      src/app.tsx
      src/app.test.tsx

      4 | 
    > 5 | import { Button, Input } from 'my-library'
        | ^
      6 |

      at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:491:11)
      at Object.require (src/app.tsx:5:1)
```

```
// package.json
{
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testTimeout": 30000,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json-summary",
      "text",
      "lcov"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./tests/setup.ts"
    ],
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "transform": {
      "\\.[jt]sx?$": [
        "ts-jest",
        {
          "useESM": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "useESM": true
      }
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "(.+)\\.js": "$1"
    },
    "extensionsToTreatAsEsm": [
      ".ts"
    ],
    "testEnvironmentOptions": {
      "customExportConditions": [
        ""
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```js
// tests/setup.ts
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'

import { jest } from '@jest/globals'
```

Vestions:

- NodeJS: v16.18.1
- Jest: ^28.1.3
- ts-jest: ^28.0.7
- typescript: ^4.7.4

Below are the configurations for my component library to make it tree-shaking:

```
// rollup.config.js

import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace'
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer'
import cssnano from 'cssnano'
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts'
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external'
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser'
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'

const pkg = require('./package.json')

const INPUT_DIR = 'src/components/'

const EXTERNAL = ['react', 'react-dom', 'quill', 'primereact', 'node-emoji']

const REPLACE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS = {
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production'),
  preventAssignment: true,
}

const RESOLVE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS = {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
}

const COMMONJS_PLUGIN_OPTIONS = {
  exclude: INPUT_DIR + '**',
  sourceMap: false,
}

const POSTCSS_PLUGIN_OPTIONS = {
  plugins: [autoprefixer, cssnano()],
  extract: 'bundle.css',
  extensions: ['.css', '.scss'],
  sourceMap: false,
}

const TERSER_PLUGIN_OPTIONS = {
  compress: {
    keep_infinity: true,
    pure_getters: true,
    reduce_funcs: false,
  },
}

const PLUGINS = [
  peerDepsExternal(),
  typescript(),
  replace(REPLACE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS),
  resolve(RESOLVE_PLUGIN_OPTIONS),
  commonjs(COMMONJS_PLUGIN_OPTIONS),
  postcss(POSTCSS_PLUGIN_OPTIONS),
  terser(TERSER_PLUGIN_OPTIONS),
]

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        format: 'esm',
        dir: 'dist',
        preserveModules: true,
        preserveModulesRoot: 'src',
        sourcemap: true,
        exports: 'named',
      },
    ],
    plugins: PLUGINS,
    external: EXTERNAL,
  },
  {
    input: 'dist/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: pkg.types, format: 'esm' }],
    external: [/\.css$/, /\.scss$/],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
]
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Please, work!",
  "homepage": "/",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production rollup -c"
  },
  "sideEffects": [
    "**/*.css",
    "**/*.scss"
  ]
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ESNext"],
    "plugins": [{"name": "typescript-tslint-plugin"}],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "strict": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "**/*.stories.tsx"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without knowing your directory structure, but probably just need an entry in `moduleNameMapper` to let jest know where to find my-library.